# How to write a method(common method) in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, rake-task

*I am new guy for write ruby file*

> I have wrote a task in ruby script, but there is a lot of repeated code in that task. So i need write a common method for that.

This is my task in ruby file

```
    install_projects = [ 
  'Cooperativa.Hermes.Application.Host.Console', 
  'Cooperativa.Hermes.Denormalizer.Host.Console', 
  'Cooperativa.Hermes.WebApi.Host.Console',
]

setup_projects = [ 
  'Cooperativa.Hermes.Setup.Console' 
]

replay_projects = [
  'Cooperativa.Hermes.EventReplayer.Console'
]

task :restore do

 install_projects.each do |project|
    restore_folder = "#{install}/#{project}"
    FileUtils.rm_rf restore_folder
    FileUtils.cp_r("#{backup_folder}/#{project}", restore_folder)
  end  
  setup_projects.each do |project|
    restore_folder = "#{install}/#{project}"
    FileUtils.rm_rf restore_folder
    FileUtils.cp_r("#{backup_folder}/#{project}", restore_folder)
  end   
  replay_projects.each do |project|
    restore_folder = "#{install}/#{project}"
    FileUtils.rm_rf restore_folder
    FileUtils.cp_r("#{backup_folder}/#{project}", restore_folder)
  end    
end
```

See

```
 restore_folder = "#{install}/#{project}"
        FileUtils.rm_rf restore_folder
        FileUtils.cp_r("#{backup_folder}/#{project}", restore_folder)
```

the above code is a repeated code.

> I need re-factored into a separate method or common method.  How can i do this? have you any idea?

**How to write a method in ruby script for my task?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

```
#refactor the proc

anonymous = lambda do |project|
  restore_folder = "#{install}/#{project}"
  FileUtils.rm_rf restore_folder
  FileUtils.cp_r("#{backup_folder}/#{project}", restore_folder)
end

install_projects.each &anonymous
```

Or loop everything at once:

```
( install_projects + setup_projects + replay_projects).each do |project|
```

Otherwise, what about extracting everything into a class where you can have your own methods and variables?

```
class RestoreData

  attr_reader :install, :backup_root

  def initialize(install, backup_root)
    @install     = install
    @backup_root = backup_root
  end

  def call
    projects.each do |project|
      clean_project_folder(project)
      restore_backup(project)
    end   
  end

  private

  def clean_project_folder(project)
    FileUtils.rm_rf restore_folder(project)
  end

  def restore_backup(project)
    FileUtils.cp_r(backup_folder(project), restore_folder(project))
  end

  def backup_folder(project)
    "#{backup_root}/#{project}"
  end

  def restore_folder(project)
    "#{install}/#{project}"
  end

  def projects
    install_projects + setup_projects + replay_projects
  end

  def install_projects
    [
      'Cooperativa.Hermes.Application.Host.Console', 
      'Cooperativa.Hermes.Denormalizer.Host.Console', 
      'Cooperativa.Hermes.WebApi.Host.Console',
    ]
  end

  def setup_projects
    [ 
      'Cooperativa.Hermes.Setup.Console' 
    ]
  end

  def replay_projects
    [
      'Cooperativa.Hermes.EventReplayer.Console'
    ]
  end
end
```

and your rake task:

```
task :restore do
  RestoreData.new(install, backup_folder).call
end
```

Comment: The `install_projects and  setup_projects and replay_projects`  is a array, So is it working? I think the each loop is a just risk for me. So can you give me a method, with pass parameter?

Comment: +1 but this one a good idea. I need a method, if that not possible, then i will do your idea . Thanks

Comment: a cheap way would be to define the method in the same file but I dont recommend this, if you need abstraction, create a dedicated file/class

Answer (score 1):

This is using a method:

```
def do_restore(project, install, backup_folder)
  restore_folder = "#{install}/#{project}"
  FileUtils.rm_rf restore_folder
  FileUtils.cp_r("#{backup_folder}/#{project}", restore_folder)
end

task :restore do

  install_projects.each { |project| do_restore(project, install, backup_folder) }
  setup_projects.each { |project| do_restore(project, install, backup_folder) }
  replay_projects.each { |project| do_restore(project, install, backup_folder) }

end
```

Though I think this might be a better solution for you (as suggested by @apneadiving):

```
(install_projects + setup_projects + replay_projects).each do |project|
  restore_folder = "#{install}/#{project}"
  FileUtils.rm_rf restore_folder
  FileUtils.cp_r("#{backup_folder}/#{project}", restore_folder)
end
```

Since you are actually iterating over three arrays, doing the same thing, this is just like if you added the three arrays together, and iterated over the *joined* array. To join two arrays together, you can use the `+` operator - `[1,2]+[3,4]==[1,2,3,4]`, so `install_projects + setup_projects + replay_projects` is simply a long list of projects, concatenated together:

```
install_projects = [ 
  'Cooperativa.Hermes.Application.Host.Console', 
  'Cooperativa.Hermes.Denormalizer.Host.Console', 
  'Cooperativa.Hermes.WebApi.Host.Console',
]

setup_projects = [ 
  'Cooperativa.Hermes.Setup.Console' 
]

replay_projects = [
  'Cooperativa.Hermes.EventReplayer.Console'
]

(install_projects + setup_projects + replay_projects) == [
  'Cooperativa.Hermes.Application.Host.Console', 
  'Cooperativa.Hermes.Denormalizer.Host.Console', 
  'Cooperativa.Hermes.WebApi.Host.Console',
  'Cooperativa.Hermes.Setup.Console',
  'Cooperativa.Hermes.EventReplayer.Console'
]
```

Comment: surely +1 for this. I don't know it is correct. Are you confirm it? This is working for me?

Comment: Both should be correct. The second one is more 'ruby-like'.

Comment: `install_projects = [ 
  'Cooperativa.Hermes.Application.Host.Console', 
  'Cooperativa.Hermes.Denormalizer.Host.Console', 
  'Cooperativa.Hermes.WebApi.Host.Console',
]

setup_projects = [ 
  'Cooperativa.Hermes.Setup.Console' 
]

replay_projects = [
  'Cooperativa.Hermes.EventReplayer.Console'
]
` this is for my array variables . The secode option is correct for this?

Comment: See my question one more time

Comment: this is exactly my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22069042/how-to-write-a-methodcommon-method-in-ruby#comment33466484_22069104

Comment: Added an explanation to my solution